# Select a random element out of an object/array based on the percent chance of it showing up

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
"rarity": {
    "Common": "60",
    "Uncommon": "25",
    "Rare": "10",
    ...
    "Legendary": "0.01",
    "Mythical": "0.001",
}
```

The object is set up as 'Name': '% chance', so Common has a 60% chance of showing up, whereas Mythical has a 1 in 100,000 chance of showing up (0.001%)

I want to be able to (Quickly) select a random element based on the percentage chance of it showing up, but I have zero ideas where to begin.

If this is in the wrong StackExchange please let me know, it's programming-related but heavily math-based.

Comment: the probabilities don't add to 1, does that mean that sometimes nothing will be chosen? or are the probabilities relative?

Comment: Are the sum of them equals to 100?

Comment: @pilchard it's a slow and not-so-good way of doing it

Comment: @atanay that doesn't stop it from being a duplicate, and only indicates that better answers should be provided there.

Comment: so should I copy my answer to there?

Comment: I would say yes, and flag as duplicate here, that way duplicate questions all point to a single pool of answers

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by taking a random number between 0 and 100000:

```
const rnd = Math.random() * 100000;
```

Now, you need to divide the number by **1000** since you want to take into account up to 3 decimals after comma for `"Mythical": "0.001"`

```
const percent = rnd / 1000;
```

Last, just take the key of the number that contains the `percent` variable.

#### Example

```js
const rarity = {
    "Common": "60",
    "Uncommon": "25",
    "Rare": "10",
    "More rare": "4.989",  // to fill the rest of percentage
    "Legendary": "0.01",
    "Mythical": "0.001"
}

const rnd = Math.random() * 100000;

const percent = rnd / 1000;

let result = null, acc = 0;

Object.keys(rarity).forEach(key => {
  if (result === null && percent > 100 - rarity[key] - acc)
    result = key;
  acc += parseFloat(rarity[key]);
});

console.log(percent + " %", result);
```

Here you can test how many times each possibility appears in a 100000 loop

```js
const rarity = {
    "Common": "60",
    "Uncommon": "25",
    "Rare": "10",
    "More rare": "4.989",  // to fill the rest of percentage
    "Legendary": "0.01",
    "Mythical": "0.001"
}


let testNumber = 100000;
const testResults = {};

while (0 < testNumber--) {

  const rnd = Math.random() * 100000;

  const percent = rnd / 1000;

  let result = null, acc = 0;

  Object.keys(rarity).forEach(key => {
    if (result === null && percent > 100 - rarity[key] - acc)
      result = key;
    acc += parseFloat(rarity[key]);
  });
  
  if (!testResults[result])
    testResults[result] = 0;
    
  testResults[result]++;

}

console.log(testResults);
```

Comment: @atanay why do you say that?

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. still, each query is in linear time which is less efficient then logarithmic.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by:

1. dividing the 0 to 1 segment into sections for each element based on their probability (For example, an element with probability 60% will take 60% of the segment).
2. generating a random number and check in which segment it lands.

**STEP 1**

make a prefix sum array for the probability array, each value in it will signify where its corresponding section ends.

**For example**:
If we have probabilities: 60% (0.6), 30%, 5%, 3%, 2%. the prefix sum array will be: `[0.6,0.9,0.95,0.98,1]`

so we will have a segment divided like this (approximately): `[            |      | ||]`

**STEP 2**

generate a random number between 0 and 1, and find it's lower bound in the prefix sum array. the index you'll find is the index of the segment that the random number landed in

Here's how you can implement this method:

```js
let obj = {
    "Common": "60",
    "Uncommon": "25",
    "Rare": "10",
    "Legendary": "0.01",
    "Mythical": "0.001"
}
// turning object into array and creating the prefix sum array:
let sums = [0]; // prefix sums;
let keys = [];
for(let key in obj) {
    keys.push(key);
    sums.push(sums[sums.length-1] + parseFloat(obj[key])/100);
}
sums.push(1);
keys.push('NONE');
// Step 2:
function lowerBound(target, low = 0, high = sums.length - 1) {
    if (low == high) {
        return low;
    }
    const midPoint = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
  
    if (target < sums[midPoint]) {
        return lowerBound(target, low, midPoint);
    } else if (target > sums[midPoint]) {
        return lowerBound(target, midPoint + 1, high);
    } else {
        return midPoint + 1;
    }
}

function getRandom() {
    return lowerBound(Math.random());
}

console.log(keys[getRandom()], 'was picked!');
```

hope you find this helpful. If you need any clarifications please ask

**Note:**
(In Computer Science) the lower bound of a value in a list/array is the smallest element that is greater or equal to it. for example, array:`[1,10,24,99]` and value 12. the lower bound will be the element with value 24.
When the array is sorted from smallest to biggest (like in our case) finding the lower bound of every value can be done extremely quickly with binary searching (O(log(n))).

EDIT: added code example

Comment: Potential problem with you method, is that I didn't paste the entire object. There's a 1 in a billion chance, so I'd have to generate a billion sections. Would that be an issue?

Comment: No, the whole point of this solution is that the probabilities themself don't affect the efficiency in any way. only the number of elements affects it.